# Фильтрация массива js по нескольким значения

Tags: javascript, массивы, фильтрация

Пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию массива по выбранным параметрам

Сам массив:

```
// массив, в котором нужно произвести фильтрацию
const array =   [
  {
    logo:            'img/retail/logo__papa_johns_pizza.png',
    title:           'Papa Johns',
    category:        ['Пицерия'],
    productCategory: ['Пица', 'Кофе', 'Слабоалкогольные напитки']
  }, {
    logo:            'img/retail/logo__starbucks.png',
    title:           'Starbucks',
    category:        ['Кофейня'],
    productCategory: ['Кофе', 'Десерты']
  }, {
    logo:            'img/retail/logo__sushiwok.png',
    title:           'SushiWok',
    category:        ['Суши'],
    productCategory: ['Суши']
  }
];
```

Фильтр в котором выбран пункт 'Пица':

```
// фильтр
let  keys = [
  {title: 'Пица', selected: true},
  {title: 'Кофе', selected: false}, 
  {title: 'Суши', selected: false},
  {title: 'Десерты', selected: false},
  {title: 'Слабоалкогольные напитки', selected: false},
  {title: 'Алкогольные напитки', selected: false}
];
```

Задача вывести из массива только те элементы , содержащие выбранный тег, в данном случае в фильтре выбран тег 'Пица'

Получаем выбранные значения фильтра в отдельный массив:

```
// выбранные значения фильтра 

var keysSelectedFilter = keys.filter((key) => key.selected == true ).map(function (key, index, keys) {
  return key.title;
});
```

`результат ["Пица"]`

Как мне отфильтровать Массив с учетом выбранного(ных) тегов, не могу разобраться.
[весь код вместе](http://jsbin.com/yazamozeka/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Все просто :)

```
// если есть в arr в категории продукта хоть один из тегов в keysSelectedFilter, то проходит фильтр
i.productCategory.some(k => keysSelectedFilter.includes(k))
```

```js
// массив, в котором нужно произвести фильтрацию
const array = [
  {
    logo:            'img/retail/logo__papa_johns_pizza.png',
    title:           'Papa Johns',
    category:        ['Пицерия'],
    productCategory: ['Пица', 'Кофе', 'Слабоалкогольные напитки']
  }, {
    logo:            'img/retail/logo__starbucks.png',
    title:           'Starbucks',
    category:        ['Кофейня'],
    productCategory: ['Кофе', 'Десерты']
  }, {
    logo:            'img/retail/logo__sushiwok.png',
    title:           'SushiWok',
    category:        ['Суши'],
    productCategory: ['Суши']
  }
];

// фильтр
let  keys = [
  {title: 'Пица', selected: true},
  {title: 'Кофе', selected: false}, 
  {title: 'Суши', selected: true},
  {title: 'Десерты', selected: false},
  {title: 'Слабоалкогольные напитки', selected: false},
  {title: 'Алкогольные напитки', selected: false}
];

// выбранные значения фильтра 
let keysSelectedFilter = keys.filter(i => i.selected).map(i => i.title)
let result = array.filter(i => 
  i.productCategory.some(k =>
    keysSelectedFilter.includes(k)
  )
)

console.log(keysSelectedFilter, result);
```

Но `includes` не работает в IE 11: https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes

Вместо него можно использовать `.indexOf(r) >= 0`