# отфильтровать массив внутреннему массиву

Tags: javascript, reactjs

начинаю программировать на js.  столкнулся с такой задачей. есть массив( имя и спислк категории. например (али гум, (бокс, тренажер,бассейн),  трайнгум,(треражер, бассейн))) вопрос как отфильтровать по категории?

```
clubs = [
    {
        "id": "56c782f18990ecf954f6e027",
        "title": "Ali Gum",
        "text": "Commodo qui incididunt ex ut ea nulla et eu aliquip duis. sint et.",
        "Categories": ["1", "3", "6"]
    },
    {
        "id": "56c782f18990ecf954f6e028",
        "title": "CrossFirst",
        "text": "Commodo qui incididunt ex ut ea nulla et eu aliquip duis. ",
        "Categories": ["1", "3", "5"]
    },
    {
        "id": "56c782f18990ecf954f6e029",
        "title": "Qazaqstan",
        "text": "Commodo qui incididunt",
        "Categories": ["1", "2", "6"]
    }
```

когда выбирает категорию я должен на селекторе должен  отфильтровать по категории

Comment: Добавьте ваш код, что вы пытались  сделать. Также приведите пример вашего массива.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/879647/256824